# Way to work with 2 css file, to prevent trouble

Tags: php, html, css

I need some idears or informations about the following situation.

I have a page with a own css style-file (Let us call it "Motherpage")

In this Motherpage i load a second html file file by php ("let us call it "Childpage").

```
    <?php
        $childpage = file_get_contents($pathtoloaclfile);
        echo $childpage;
    ?>
```

This works fine.

In the Chilpage are one or more own css-styles and css-files.

Now i have trouble with the two(or more) different css-files and styles.

Some styles broken, caused some styles from the chilpage will overrite or add or inherit to the motherstyles :-(

in the motherfile i use a prefix for every class
.motherpage body{ ... }

But it seems that that is not enought.

What i can do to make sure, that the motherstyles (also the child-styles for himself too) will work on the elements only defined in the motherstyle css.

For example, in the motherfile is no "body" Style defined, in the childstyle, is it defined. So this will affect to a lot of styles, by inherit

I hope, i could explain, whats the problem, and whats the quetion.

Thanks a lot to inspire and helping.

Comment: You should at least share some of that code in question. Currently, I'd have no clue whether your markup structure is wrong or whether your CSS contains the wrong selectors

Comment: Adding to @NicoHaase, what order are you loading the CSS files? The simple rule is the styling closest to the element takes precedence ( except for !important). Also your child styles will also inherit some values from the mother style.

Comment: may adding !important to each motherclass wont solve the problem to inherit some styles from the childpage

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is (also suggested by @jeff, in comments above), load the styles in this order, in the page where you are having styling issues.

1. motherpage_styles.css
2. childpage_styles.css

And override any specific styles required by the page in the `childpage_styles.css`.

Let's say `motherpage_styles.css` has following `CSS`

```
body {
   background-color: #eee;
}
```

And in the `childpage_styles.css` you can override and change the `background-color` like this.

```
body {
   background-color: #ff0000;
}
```

If the order is like above, then this will work without needing of `!important`. However, the class you are overriding has `!important` in the `motherpage_styles.css`, then you will have to use the `!important` flag in the overriding class in the `childpage_styles.css` as well.

Hope you will find this helpful. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

You could try loading the new page in an `iframe` so it doesn't interfere with the CSS styles.

Comment: yes, im worry, but that wont a way for me, many scripts has to work on this page, so if i do it with a iframe, i have to edit all these script and maybe some functions wont work with a iframe. so i need another way.